# SQL Case expression for date ranges between a Date Column and a Lag Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case, union

I am trying to build a dataset for Reporting in which i have to retrieve data from different tables having values. 
I have a table named 'Rate' and i need to retrieve the rate values from the 'rate' column. In this table i also have an 'eff_Date' column.

I also have a 'Date' table in which i have an 'date' column.

I want my condition to be in such a manner that if the value in the date column from the 'date' table falls between the eff_date and end_eff_date (used a lag function to get that) from the 'Rate' table then pull the value rate value.

I have tried using a SQL CASE expression to achieve this, but unable to go forward with it as i am unable to add the Lag function onto the CASE expression.

Comment: Could you show some example of your data?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using a SQL-Server

Comment: @lypskee Please find the below example for your reference:

Comment: Please write the example data as a create table and insert statement and show the expected outcome so that it is easier to see what you need. Write a query to show what you've tried so far as well.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rate](
 [CompanyNo] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Eff_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [rate] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Insert into dbo.Rate values('05','01-10-2018','245.11'),
('05','01-09-2015','234.79');


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Date](
 [CompanyNo] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ResidentNo] [int] NOT NULL,
 [date] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Insert into dbo.Date values('05','108276','08-03-2019'),
('05','108276','01-08-2016');

Answer (score 0):

This expresses your rates as a start and end dates that you can then compare to your dates:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rate]( [CompanyNo] [int] NOT NULL, [Eff_date] [datetime] NOT NULL, [rate] [nchar](10) NOT NULL ) ON [PRIMARY]
Insert into dbo.Rate values('05','01-10-2018','245.11'), ('05','01-09-2015','234.79');
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Date]( [CompanyNo] [int] NOT NULL, [ResidentNo] [int] NOT NULL, [date] [datetime] NOT NULL ) ON [PRIMARY]
Insert into dbo.Date values('05','108276','08-03-2019'), ('05','108276','01-08-2016');

WITH cte as (
SELECT *,LEAD(eff_date) OVER (ORDER BY eff_date) as end_eff_date  FROM rate
)
SELECT * FROM date
INNER JOIN cte
    ON cte.Eff_date <= date.date
    AND (date.date < cte.end_eff_date OR cte.end_eff_date IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 SELECT a.* FROM 
 (SELECT [CompanyNo],[Eff_date], LAG( [Eff_date], 1, Null) OVER (PARTITION BY  [CompanyNo]
     ORDER BY [Eff_date]) AS end_eff_date ,[rate] FROM [dbo].[Rate]) AS A
     LEFT JOIN
     [dbo].[Date] AS B
     ON A.[CompanyNo]=B.[CompanyNo]
     WHERE B.[date] BETWEEN  a.end_eff_date and a.[Eff_date]
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use `APPLY` to get the one row that you want:

```
select d.date, r.*
from date d outer apply
     (select top (1) r.*
      from rates r
      where d.date >= r.eff_date
      order by r.eff_date desc
     ) r;
```

You don't need `LAG()` or `LEAD()`. `APPLY` implements what is called a *lateral join*, which is very powerful.  If you only want one column, then you can use a correlated subquery. You can think of a lateral join as a generalization of correlated subqueries.